# How to eliminate hexadecimal values and rename the tags in XML document

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML files like below.

1. Having hexadecimal values, this type of XML file SSIS XML Task not accepting.
2. Tags like `<FIRST.NAME>` ,I need to replace `<FIRST.NAME>` with `<FIRST_NAME>`.

I have to change like around 40 tags in each XML File.

How can I achieve these two things, can anyone put me in right direction ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is assuming you mean hexadecimal character references when you say "hexadecimal value". If this is incorrect, please clarify.

Just by running your XML through an XSLT processor should resolve your hexadecimal references. (I tested with Xalan, Saxon 6.5.5, and Saxon-HE/PE/EE 9.3.05.)

The only thing you need other than an identity transform is another template to rename your elements.

**XML Input**

```
<some.doc>
  <some.element attr="test">
    <another.element>Here is a hex ref: &#x3A9;</another.element>
    <another.element>Here is a hex ref: &#x3A3;</another.element>
  </some.element>
</some.doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()|processing-instruction()|comment()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(name(),'.','_')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>     
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<some_doc>
   <some_element attr="test">
      <another_element>Here is a hex ref: Ω</another_element>
      <another_element>Here is a hex ref: Σ</another_element>
   </some_element>
</some_doc>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. its working fine for me. Coming to Hexa Decimal in my source XML have some hex symbols those are something like ^(not exactly) how can i remove or overcome those symbols while i am giving that XML as a source to XML Task in SSIS.